# using img as background for <h1>

Tags: html, css

At the moment i'm working with CSS (really new to it) and i want to have a background img for headers - managed to make it work - however, strugling to make img width adjust to the length of the header (content)

```
h2{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-size: 20px; 
 padding-left: 20px; 
 padding-top: 10px;
 margin-top:10px;
 color:white;
 }
span h2{
 background-image: url(border.gif);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: bottom left;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
```

As you can see i've tried to inclose  inside inline element such as , tried making  as an inline element too, but can't make it work.

Any help would be much apriciated

Comment: don't wrap headings within span

Comment: don't see any h1 in the css

Comment: try reversing the `span h2` rule to `h2 span` and nest the span in your header instead of the other way around

Comment: If you want to make a background image adjust to the width of some element, you first need to decide how this should be happen when the width:height ration of the image is different from that of the element. You should explain this in the question itself. You should also show sample HTML code and make it valid and consistent with your description. Moreover, you should clarify whether the image needs to be a background image or whether one can use a content image (and lay the heading text over it).

Answer (score 0):

`Span` is inline element and block headline shouldn't be inside.

If you want to set background to `h2`, set it to `h2`.

```
h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    padding-left: 20px; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    color:white;
    background: url('border.gif') left bottom / 100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

In HTML there will be just `h2`, no `span` around.

Comment: how do i make the width of an img same as the length of header content? thats my main issue

Comment: @GalimbekSagidenov: h2 as a block element has the same width as its parent (header in this case), so the background image will over the whole header width. And it doesn't matter if h2 contains long content or just one character.

Comment: if i use 'display:inline' so it behaves like an inline elemet and then delete 'no-repeat' - img goes as fast as the content of the header - but the image repeats (obv) how do i make it so the img length matches the content, but does not repeat, but stretches instead? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @GalimbekSagidenov: is there any reason to use `display: inline;`? Give me link to your site, without the context there are many variants how to do what you need.

Comment: can not link the website - it is in a closed network. The idea is simple - every header has a background img that is the same length as the headers content - with no repeats - stretches if need be. It is a broadcast page i am doing for the company i work for

Comment: @GalimbekSagidenov: I've updated my answer: `background: url('border.gif') left bottom / 100% 100% no-repeat;`. It works when you don't declare `display: inline;` - headlines are block elements. If you need (I don't know why) headlines inline, add a div with background around. `<div><h2>headline</h2></div>`, `div {background: ...;} h2 {font: ...; padding: ...; etc.}`.